# No toma los datos en la funcion GaussJordan

Tags: c, matrices

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Estoy intentando hacer el metodo de Gauss Jordan en C.

Todo va bien asta que tiene que hacer el metodo.

Lo tengo en funciones.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <conio.h>
  

  //funcion de llenado de Matriz
  void llenarmatriz(int tam,float m[10][10]){
    int i=0,j=0;

    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
    printf("\nFila %d",i+1);
    for(j=0;j<tam+1;j++){
        if(j==tam){
            printf("\nResultado: ");
            scanf("%f",&m[i][j]);
        }
        else{
            printf("\nColumna %d: ",j+1);
            scanf("%f",&m[i][j]);
        }
        
    }//fin del 2do for

}//fin del 1er for

//return m[i][j];
}//Fin del llenado de la matriz

//Impresion de la matriz
void imprimirmatriz(int tam, float m[10][10]){
int i=0,j=0;
printf("\nEl sistema es el siguiente: \n");
for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
    for(j=0;j<tam+1;j++){
        if(j==tam){
            printf(" | %.0f",m[i][j]);
        }
        else{
            printf(" %.0f ",m[i][j]);
        }
        
    }//fin del 2do For
    printf("\n");
}//fin del 1er For
}//fin de imprimir matriz

void GaussJordan(int tam, float m[10][10]){
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
float c,x[10];
//Oncontrar los elementos de la diagonal de la matriz
for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
    for(j=0; j<tam; j++){
        if(i != j)
        {
            c=m[j][i]/m[j][j];
            for(k=0; k<tam+1; k++){
                m[j][k] = m[j][k]-c*m[i][k];
            }//fin del for dentro del if
        }//fin del if
    }//fin de 2do for
}//fin del 1er for

//Mostramos la solucion
for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
    x[i] = m[i][tam+1]/m[i][i];
}//fin del for

printf("\n\n\tLa solucion es: ");
for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
    printf("\n\t Incognita %d = %.2f\n",i+1,x[i]);
}//fin del for
}//Fin da GaussJordan


 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int tam = 0;
    float m[10][10];
    char op;
    do{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tMETODO GAUSS JORDAN\n");
    printf("\n\t\tIngresa el tamano de la matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&tam);
    llenarmatriz(tam,m);
    imprimirmatriz(tam,m);
    GaussJordan(tam,m);
    printf("\n\n Quieres repetir el programa? \t S/N \n Opcion:");
    scanf("%s",&op);
}while(op == 's'|| op=='S');
return 0;       
}//fin del main
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la imagen no me da solucion. Siempre pone 0.
Las funciones de llenado y de impresion de matriz funciona bien.

Intente encontrar la inversa de la matriz y de nuevo no imprime nada. Me arroja 0 no logro entender el porque sucede esto.
Aunque ponga un tamaño mas chico de la matriz sigue en imprimir 0 en la solucion.

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Amigo, para poder probar tu codigo necesitamos que nos compartas tambien la funcion de llenar matriz y la de imprimir matriz. Si no no puedo poner el codigo en mi ordenador y probarlo

Comment: No me deja poner todo el codigo

Comment: //funcion de llenado de Matriz
void llenarmatriz(int tam,float m[10][10]){
 int i=0,j=0;
 //int r;
 for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
  printf("\nFila %d",i+1);
  for(j=0;j<tam+1;j++){
   if(j==tam){
    printf("\nResultado: ");
    scanf("%f",&m[i][j]);
   }
   else{
    printf("\nColumna %d: ",j+1);
    scanf("%f",&m[i][j]);
   }
   
  }//fin del 2do for
 
 }//fin del 1er for
 
 //return m[i][j];
}//Fin del llenado de la matriz

Comment: //Impresion de la matriz
void imprimirmatriz(int tam, float m[10][10]){
 int i=0,j=0;
 printf("\nEl sistema es el siguiente: \n");
 for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
  for(j=0;j<tam+1;j++){
   if(j==tam){
    printf(" | %.0f",m[i][j]);
   }
   else{
    printf(" %.0f ",m[i][j]);
   }
   
  }//fin del 2do For
  printf("\n");
 }//fin del 1er For
}//fin de imprimir matriz

Comment: @Pablochaches en los comentarios agregue las 2 funciones faltantes

Comment: Amigo, puedes editar la preguta para añadir el codigo. EL problema de como lo colocaste es que despues tendira que formaterarlo en el editor

Comment: Solo así por encima: `x[i] = m[i][tam+1]/m[i][i];`. ¿ `tam + 1` no estará accediendo a posiciones incorrectas de `m` ?

Comment: @Pablochaches Lo intente hacer asi, pero me dice que es demaciado codigo. deja lo intento de nuevo

Comment: @Trauma le quite lo cambia a ``x[i] = m[i][tam]/m[i][i];`` y si me dio resultados. pero no me dio los correctos.

Comment: @Giovanni Si es cierto, no deja que sea demaciado codigo. Lo que puedes hacer es explicar un poco mas en texto lo que haces. Asi te dejara meter mas codigo

Comment: @Pablochaches ya me dejo poner todo el codigo.

Comment: @Giovanni Muchas gracias